# Printing an incremented character using cout

Tags: c++, pointers

Why do I have to typecast the pointer in the following example inside the `code` function in order to return values of type `char` since I already have declared it as a constant pointer to char in the function definition?

In particular `cout << (*p + 1)` the result is in integer format, while when changing that to `cout << (char) (*p + 1)` then the result is displayed in char format, since I am typecasting it.

Does the `<<` operator have some default arguments as to what type to display?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void code(const char* p);

int main()
{
    code("This is a test");

    return 0;
}

void code(const char* p)
{
    while(*p)
    {
        cout << (*p + 1);
        p++;
    }
}
```

Comment: C is not C++ is not C! Do not add unrelated tags.

Comment: Can you clarify whether you are intending to add 1 to the character? (i.e. are you trying to output `Uijt!jt!b!uftu`)

Comment: Yes as a simple example i was intending to add 1 to the character and i was trying to display this in character format.

Comment: `p` is a **pointer to const char**, not **constant pointer to char** as you write.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`*p` is `const char` and adding `1` ([integer literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal)) promotes it to `int` (See numeric promotions in [this link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast)). You have to cast it back to `char`:

```
cout << static_cast<char>(*p + 1); // abandon C-style cast
```

And yes, `std::ostream::operator<<` is overloaded to treat different types differently.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is a problem o type promotion then!

Comment: IIRC, adding two values of type `char` will yield and `int` because of default integral promotion, so casting the `1` will not do.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
cout << (*p+1);
```

to

```
cout << *(p+1);
```

This works for the reasons stated by @LogicStuff.

Comment: This also outputs a different character (although it's not quite clear from OP's post which version he intended)